# Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger Function MessageReceiver error, The operation was canceled

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-function-app

Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger Function randomly throwing operation canceled exception.
This exception is not thrown from code, looks like something wrong when azure function trying to receive messages from service bus queue, but not sure.
Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful. Also, have you tried Microsoft support?

Comment: @SeanFeldman yes, we raised this issue to Microsoft and they recommended to upgrade "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" version, I have upgraded it to "4.1.2" and issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft's recommendation upgraded Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus SDK version to "4.1.2" and issue is resolved.